# jQuery overflow-y update to scroll briefly shows but then reverts to no-scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I find that when I update a `div`'s `overflow-y` property to `scroll` the change happens only for a moment (I can just barely see the scroll var flicker in and out), and then the `div` reverts to its original `overflow-y: hidden` status.

Here's the code. First, I create a bunch of `div` elements like so:

```
   $('#toAppend').append("<div id = '"+divName+"' class = 'unselected' style = 'overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden; float:left;'></div>");
```

Later on, when a div is clicked, I want to expand it and add a scroll bar so I use the following in `click()`:

```
div.css("overflow-y", "scroll");
```

When I then click on a div, I very fleetingly see the scroll bar and then it disappears. There is no other `css` or `jQuery` touching this `overflow-y` property. Why doesn't the change remain?

Working example [here](http://sunnysideworks.nyc/test/test).

Here's what I've tried to trouble-shoot:

- I already have `CSS` classes that correspond to the selected and unselected states that regulate scrolling, so I tried adjusting `overflow-y` to `scroll` vs `hidden`. This also did not show any results.
- Even though jQuery can use `overflow-y` I also tried calling `css("overflowY"...` using camel case. This also made no difference.
- There aren't any error messages in the browser, and all other related updates for click events are happening.

Here is a larger code sample covering most of what is done:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // set up sizing variables
    width =  $('#toAppend').width()*.9;
    height = $('#toAppend').height()*.9;       
    widthPer = width/pageArray.length;
    heightPer = height*.2;

    // generate 1 div for each element in pageArray
    for(i = 1; i <= pageArray.length; i++){

        var divName = "div_"+i
        $('#toAppend').append("<div id = '"+divName+"' class = 'unselected' style = 'overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden; float:left;'></div>");
        $("#"+divName).load(pageArray[i-1]).css("width", Math.round(widthPer*PORTION_DIV)).css("height", heightPer).css("background-color", COLORS[i-1])
            .css('cursor', 'pointer').css("border-radius", BORDER_RADIUS)

        // expand div user clicks on and collapse other sections
            .click(function(event){

                var div = "#div_"+event.currentTarget.id.slice(-1);    
                if($(div).hasClass("unselected") || $(div).hasClass("almostSelected")){
                    var shrinkString = ""
                    var widthPerSmall = Math.round((1-MULTIPLE_TO)*width/(pageArray.length - 1));
                    var divToShrink = "";

                    // generate string of all divs other than selected one to shrink them down simultaneously
                    for(ii = 1; ii <= pageArray.length; ii++){
                        if(ii !== Number(event.currentTarget.id.slice(-1))){
                            var divShrink = "#div_"+ii;
                            shrinkString = shrinkString + divShrink +", " ;
                            if($(divShrink).hasClass("selected")){
                                divToShrink = divShrink;
                                $(divToShrink).switchClass("selected", "unselected", SHORT_TIME)

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // shrink elements in a given order with nested callbacks
                    shrinkString = shrinkString.slice(0, -2);
                    $(shrinkString)
                        .animate({ width: widthPerSmall, height: heightPer}, LONG_TIME, function(){
                            $(div).animate({width: Math.round(MULTIPLE_TO*width), height: height}, LONG_TIME, function(){
                                if(divToShrink.length > 1){
                                    toShrink = divToShrink.slice(-1)
                                    $(divToShrink).load(pageArray[toShrink-1])
                                        .css("background-color", COLORS[toShrink-1])
                                }
                            })
                                .switchClass(["unselected", "almostSelected"], "selected", LONG_TIME)
                                .load(longPageArray[Number(event.currentTarget.id.slice(-1))-1 ]).attr("class", "selected")
                                .css("background-color", "white").css("border", BORDER+COLORS[Number(event.currentTarget.id.slice(-1))-1])
                                .css("overflow-y", "scroll");

                        })
                    // this should be called only for first click, when no elements are yet selected
                    if(divToShrink.length < 1) $(div).animate({width: Math.round(MULTIPLE_TO*width), height: height}, LONG_TIME).switchClass(["unselected", "almostSelected"], "selected", LONG_TIME).load(longPageArray[Number(event.curren\
tTarget.id.slice(-1))-1 ]).attr("class", "selected").css("background-color", "white").css("border", BORDER+COLORS[Number(event.currentTarget.id.slice(-1))-1]).css("overflow-y", "scroll");

                }


            })
    }
```

Comment: Put relevant code in the question itself (Not ***fragments***, actual, full - yet minimal, code)

Comment: @Amit I've updated with code

Comment: Can you create a basic jsfiddle example of your issue? You still did not include all relevant code. Have you tried adding to jquery div.css("overflow", "") ? Maybe somehow that overflow is overriding your overflow-y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply your css in the **callback of your animate function** for expanding divs, instead of chaining it after `animate()` is called like you are currently doing. Chaining jQuery animation methods adds those functions to the `fx` queue, but non-animated methods like `css()` do not get added to that queue. Instead they are fired immediately. Taking a peek at the [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/99e8ff1baa7ae341e94bb89c3e84570c7c3ad9ea/src/effects.js#L181-L188) you can see that when animating elements, jQuery changes the overflow to hidden and then changes it back to what it thinks the original overflow properties are when it is done with the animation. In this case, because of the async chain, jQuery goes with its original inline style instead of the one set in chained `css()` method. As a rule of thumb, if you are calling any jQuery method that is not an animation, don't chain it but put it in the callback.

The relevant block of code needs to be changed to this:

```
$(div).animate({width: Math.round(MULTIPLE_TO*width),height: height}, 
                LONG_TIME, 
                function(){
                     if(divToShrink.length > 1){
                         toShrink = divToShrink.slice(-1)
                         $(divToShrink).load(pageArray[toShrink-1])
                         .css("background-color", COLORS[toShrink-1])
                      }
                      //APPLY THIS IN CALLBACK
                      $(this).css("overflow-y", "scroll");
                })
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1a8wfybs/)

While jQuery will change the overflow to hidden for the animation, as you found out originally, by chaining that method you actually can override that for the duration of the animation. So if that is important to you, you can continue chaining the method *and* add it to the callback. It looks like in your particular instance, there is a conflict with the other animation method that would cause the overflow to revert to hidden for its duration, so the overflow will flicker. So that's up to you whether you include both or just keep the one call in the callback of animated methods.

Also as a side note, I noticed that you always chain your jquery `css()` functions on the same elements. You know you can save all properties as an object and just pass that in as a parameter to save yourself all of those function calls?

Comment: That did it. I'll award you the bounty as soon as I am able. Why is it that since it can't be animated it has to be in the callback and can't just be chained on as I had it? Thanks again! ( and ps thanks for the css tip. I know this but get lazy in my own bad way. good to get called onit.

Comment: I edited my answer with a much more detailed explanation of *why* you are seeing this effect. Also, haha I only added that css tip because I think it would actually make your coding process much *easier* on yourself - you're doing too much work now!